# How to expose the JavaScript interface for an embedded Flash object?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, externalinterface

JavaScript and the Flash Player can exchange data via Flash's ExternalInterface mechanism: you register ActionScript functions that you would like to be able to be called from JavaScript.

My question: How can I figure out what ActionScript functions of a Flash object are available for me to call from JavaScript (assuming they are not documented)?

Is there a programatic way to do this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can't enumerate them directly (they won't be listed in a for..in loop), but you can test for each one explicitly...

```
var swf = document.getElementById('theID');
alert('someMethod' in swf);  // will alert true if 'someMethod' is exposed via ExternalInterface.addCallback
```

this might fail if called during $(document).ready or window.onload - the swiff must be 'initialized' (loaded and registered) for the exposed methods to be available at all.

Comment: But won't I still have to "guess" the right method names with that technique? I don't think that will do the trick. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you could always XMLHttpRequest  a copy of the .swf, uncompress it with a javascript based zlib/gz/uncompress routine (they exist) and either search it for strings to test, or write a super simple parser, copy some source from here  https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm